# Finding a continuous function satisfying $f^{(k)}(k)=k$ for any whole number $k$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

I am having some knowledge in ordinary differential equations. I think my knowledge is not low, but average. However, I could not use my knowledge to solve, or even to start solving the following problem;

> Find a continuous function, $f(x)$, that satisfies $f^{(k)}(k)=k$ for any whole number $k$, i.e. $f(0)=0, f'(1)=1, f''(2)=2$, and so on.

I am not sure if that is a difficult problem, an average-difficulty problem, a simple problem, or an impossible problem.

If this problem can be solved, where the function is expressed as infinite sum, then is it possible if we have the restriction that $f$ has finitely many terms?

I had not have this question from a book or exam, but it popped up into my mind, and I am keen to get to the solution.

---

Forgive my poor English, hopefully my problem is clear.

I am not asking for a solution, but just asking for the way to start.

Your help is highly appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: One way to find such a function is to construct a sequence of functions $g_k$ that satisfy $g^{(k)}(k)=k$ (so only one of the conditions) and are supported in a small enough neighborhood of $k$ and then choose $f=\sum_{k=0}^\infty g_k$

Comment: You could do it with infinitely many terms by a polynomial of degree $k$, but I have no idea how to solve it with finitely many terms. Also i am not sure if the coefficients would converge.

Comment: so to clarify, you want a function which satisfies:
$$f(0)=0$$
$$f'(1)=1$$
$$f''(2)=2$$
etc

Comment: It cannot be represented as a polynomial with a finite number of terms as there would be a point at which $f^{(n)}(n)\ne n$ which would contradict the requirements

Comment: @HenryLee who said the requirement is that the function to be a polynomial? Finite number of terms may or may not be a polynomial, ((for example only)), what can you say about $y=\sin(x)+e^{-x}$ .. is it a polynomial?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari it was an observation, so clearly it is not a polynomial

Comment: @HenryLee Then could you please tell me what do you mean by "which would contradict the requirement". What was the requirement?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari the requirement was $f^{(k)}(k)=k$ but polynomial of order $n$ would have an always zero $n+1$th derivative

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same function but we can solve $f^{(k)}(a)=k$ by using taylor series:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$
then using the requirements above we get:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(x-a)^n}{(n-1)^!}$$
$$f(x)=(x-a)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(x-a)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=(x-a)e^{x-a}$$

---

maybe you can use taylor series or some form of approximation to line it up into a useable form e.g.
$$f(0)=0$$
$$f'(1)=1=f'(0)+...$$